# Password hashing using bcrypt in nodejs

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am using `"bcrypt": "^3.0.4"` and I have the latest stable version of node. The issue I am facing is when the user attempts to login. With the correct password the initial login attempt is always unsuccessful while the second attempt is successful. I would like to know where I am getting it wrong. The assumption here is that the user has entered an email/username that is available in the database, mongodb in this case.

```
User.findOne({ "email": user.email }, (err, ruser) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                bcrypt.compare(user.password, hash).then(function (res) {
                    if (res) {
                        pass = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        pass = false;
                    }
                });
                res.json(pass);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post `logs` at failure time

Comment: @Shahzeb There are no errors in the console if that's what you mean. I removed the hash part i.e.  `bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10 .. ` and retried, but the outcome is the same. `console.log(ruser.password)` shows the password as retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code.

1. `bcrypt.compare` is async and the `res.json` is outside of the .then, so `res.json` is actually ran before comparison or `pass` it set.
2. `pass` is not defined with `var`/`let`, so `pass` becomes a global variable and this is **serious** security implication, because two user logging in at the same time will cause a race condition (e.g. `pass` from session A may be res.json-ed in session B)

It works as a result of the above two errors, in the first request, `res.json` is executed before comparison and `pass` is not set yet, so it returns null. On the second request, again `res.json` is executed before compare, however this time the `pass` contains the value of the last compare, so what you are getting is actually last compare's result.

In addition, it is ok if you are just testing, otherwise this code does nothing, because this code generates the hash for the given password, and compares the given password to the generated hash, which definitely should be always true.

Comment: Thank you Eric. Correct I am just testing at the moment. So I tried to change it up a bit. `bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function (result) { ` wherein `hash` is the retrieved hashed password from the database and `password` is the password the user entered in the form. Why is the compare not working ? I went through the bcrypt documentation and the mini example there seems clear enough. What am i missing ? I am referring to bcrypt.compare here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { hash, compare } from 'bcryptjs';

export const hashPassword = async (password: string): Promise<string> => {
  const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 10);
  return hashedPassword;
};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.